# Deploy to JBoss Fuse from Nexus using Jenkins

Tags: jbossfuse, fuseesb

I am looking for some guidance to deploy maven artifacts from nexus to JBoss Fuse 6.2. The few references i got was using fabric, and we are not using fabric in our current project. Jenkins to Nexus was easy. I would like to get some pointers on deploying from nexus to Fuse without using fabric profiles.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old article, but the ideas are stil valid for your use case:

http://giallone.blogspot.it/2014/05/continuous-integration-with-jboss-fuse.html

To keep it brief:
- have your jenkins job to invoke administrative operation on JBoss Fuse, either via ssh or via jmx or jolokia (jmx over rest).

Answer (score 1):

The JBoss Fuse documentation should have a section on setting you JBoss Fuse to point to your Nexus repository (maven repo) in the configuration files. Then you can deploy your application from Fuse/Karaf shell where you can then do install via `osgi:install mvn:groupId/artifactId:version` in the console.

For example
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/deploying_into_apache_karaf/esbdeploylocate

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/deploying_into_apache_karaf/ESBDeployLocateRunTime#Locate-RunTime-HttpProxy

You can either configure this in your local m2 settings.xml file, or instead configure JBoss Fuse server (karaf) with the url to your own nexus repo. You can find the configuration files in the `etc` directory.